# "Would have loved" in the book narration

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, modal-verbs, will-would

I'm reading Bloodline by F. Paul Wilson and came across the following snippet:

> Jack needed to read this. **He'd have loved** to take it home to pore
> over, but Bolton would know he'd been invaded when he found it
> missing.

The narration goes when Jack snuck into Bolton's room and now he's looking at the book.
Why does the author uses the perfect tense after the modal verb? This way it seems that Jack doesn't want to take it home right now looking at it but wanted to do that in the past

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modals followed by auxiliary *have* are almost always *irrealis* (counterfactual) conditionals.

*He would love to* would be *realis*: there was a possibility that he might yet take it home. *He would have loved to* means that he did not take it home - that possibility was not realized.

I don't agree with WS2 that there is anything sloppy about *He would have loved to take it home*. *To have taken it home* is of course possible, but English speakers often omit that sort of complexity when the temporal relationships are clear.

Comment: What would've been the difference if he'd written "He would love" and would that have been correct? (By the way, are all 3 perfects in my question correct?)

Comment: There was a big bully at school. _I'd have loved to punch his face._ I held back because his Dad was a Tory councillor and my father's boss.

Comment: Are you sure? To my mind, "He would have loved to take it home" is Past Tense for "He would love to take it home" *right now* (Present Tense). And *in that past tense context* it was effectively "still a possibility" (albeit a *remote* possibility, because of the deterrent).  The situation where that possibility was *not* realized would be "He would have loved **to have taken** it home" (but in fact he *didn't*).

Comment: Sorry Colin, but I think this is going to be my first downvote *ever* on anything you've written here!

Comment: @FumbleFingers "He would have loved to take it home" is past tense, which fits when [he] already let go of that desire due to an earlier consideration. Consider: "I would love to take you out to dinner" is an active desire. "I would have loved to take you out to dinner [but I won't because I know you're married to Bob]" is stating a present tense irrealis. If she wasn't married at the present time, he would have taken her to dinner at the present time. "I would have loved to have taken you out to dinner [before you got married to Bob]" is a past regret, and says nothing about the present.

Comment: "He would have loved to take it home" is past tense related to what time? To the moment when Jack was looking at the book or to the time when the author actually writes about the past events?

Comment: @Flater Going back to the question, I would agree that if it is a present tense "irrealis" then it is correctly worded. But most novels are written and stories told in the past tense. My presumption is that "He'd have loved..." expresses a past feeling - in which case it needs to be followed by "...to have taken it home."

Comment: I've just made a "non-edit" so I could reverse my ill-thought-through downvote. Even if it is indeed theoretically possible to distinguish between *...to **take** it home* and *...to **have taken** it home* after ***He'd have loved...***, I can't possibly argue with "English speakers often omit that sort of complexity when the temporal relationships are clear". And I definitely think it's not just pointless encouraging learners to engage with any distinction there - it's positively counterproductive. Why should learners need to be more "accurate" than the natives?

Comment: This answer is correct. "He'd have loved to take it home to pore over", when in fact he didn't take it home. The rest of the idea is implied. English uses this a LOT. Including in the past tense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The author of that sentence would not have been able to double-stack both the intention of (a) narrative past tense and (b) expressing an irrealis in the present time (relative to what the narration is narrating - i.e. his desire was to take it home "now", his desire was not that he had already taken it home in his own past). We deconstruct this sentence and you assume it must be (a) and I assume it must be (b), but there's nothing stopping it from being both, and I think that's what it is.

Comment: @Flater: Maybe. I think *this* context (nested modals with permutations of tenses) might become impossible for human brains to "grok" even faster than *I know that you know that he knows that I know that...* Just because we can say or write things doesn't mean we know *exactly* what the words mean.

Comment: @Colin I doubt modals followed by auxiliary have are almost always irrealis. For instance, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134926/would-have-done Can you harmonize that with your theory?

Comment: @KinzleB: you're right, I should have said "[deontic modals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_modality) followed by auxiliary have". Modals with "have" often have an epistemic reading. But this use is clearly not epistemic, unlike the one in the question you linked

Comment: @FumbleFingers Will these transformations with verbs that can have the non-finite clause as complementation   make sense: "He'd have agreed to have taken it home during his previous visit...", "He would have wanted to have taken it home during his previous visit...", "He would have hated to have taken it home during his previous visit..." or even "He would have acnowledged having taken it home during his previous visit...", "He would have payed for having taken it home during his previous visit..."

Comment: @Eugene: Constructions like those might "make sense" and/or be syntactically valid, but that doesn't mean they're idiomatic. Personally, I can't conceive of any *semantic* distinction between your *He'd have agreed **to have taken** it home...* and the natural phrasing *He'd have agreed **to take** it home*, so I would always advise the latter *(**simpler**)* phrasing. As for your other examples, they just look even more weird to me - I'm sure whatever they're *intended* to convey can be done more simply and clearly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers How can the idea of something that hadn't happened before Jack invaded Bolton's room (in the author's past, during Jack's previous invasion a week before, for example) be conveyed? I thought it should be: "He'd have loved to have taken it home during his previous invasion a week before..."? But with "agree" in the case akin, the sentense "He'd have agreed to have taken it home during his previous invasion a week before..." doesn't make sense for me (that's why I asked about that, because I may have been wrong). Because, in my view one can't agree to do something in the past.

Comment: @Eugene: As Colin points out in his answer text, *English speakers often omit that sort of complexity*. It makes no difference whether you start with *He'd have loved to...* or *He'd have agreed to...* - in both cases it's "syntactically valid" to continue with another perfect form, but native speakers usually wouldn't. The reason they "feel" different is because the "loved" one is about *what he wanted but couldn't have*, whereas the "agreed" one is telling us what the speaker thinks ***probably** would be the case* (if we were to look into the matter).

Comment: @FumbleFingers If I'm reading you right, it is not irrealis with "agree" but a presumption, expectation and "would" relays its pure modal meaning?

Comment: @Eugene: Approximately, yes. But modals are *very* complicated in English, and often depend on exact context. Without a full context, we can't say whether ***He'd have agreed...*** reflects speaker's belief that he ***did*** agree, or the assertion that ***if he had been asked** (which he **wasn't**) then he would have agreed*. But if you want to know more, you need to ask a separate question. (We can't go on littering up Colin's answer like this! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you very much! This comment of yours has been particularly beneficial!

Answer (score 5):

The reason seems simpler than the other answers to me: the narrator is describing past events. Jack needed (in the past, from the narrator's perspective) to read this, and (at that time) would have loved to ...

The alternative

> Jack needs to read this. He'd love to take it home to pore over ...

would also be perfectly acceptable, but that is not normally how fiction is written.

Comment: I ran into such a construction as: "He was willing to do that job, if he WERE put to it, for less money". Why is it "were" here and not "had been"? It is the past, from the narrator's perspective, and he could have been put to it at that time. Shouldn't it have been: "He was willing to do that job, if he HAD BEEN put to it, for less money"?

Comment: @Eugene because the act of being willing comes before the hypothetical act of being put to it. If this ordering were reversed, you might use "had been", as in "He would have been willing [...] if he had been [...]". Here the sense is that the (missed) opportunity to put it to him came before the time in focus.

Comment: Thank you. Will the following modification be correct: "He was willing to do that job, and he would be put to it if he were not so whimmy"?

Answer (score -1):

You are quite right. It is sloppy English in my view.

I think we can assunme that "He'd have loved" is short for "He would have loved". That part is not a problem.

But the whole sentence should read ***He'd have loved to have taken it home to pore over...***

**But relevant to this answer is my comment to @FumbleFingers below. I will concede that if the book is written in the present tense, or what has sometimes been described on ELU as "the historical present" - like Carlyle's *French Revolution* (unlikely) - then it is correctly worded.**

Comment: Wouldn't that seem that at that time he wanted to have already taken it home but not take it for further investigation?

Comment: @Denis I don't think so. One could say ***He would have loved to have taken it for further investigation.***

Comment: @Denis Hold on! I think I see what you mean. But if he is wishing that he had already taken it home - he would surely say either ***He wished he had taken it home*** or ***He  would have loved that he had (already) taken it home.***

Comment: Somewhat unusually, I think you are right here, and Colin is wrong! See my comment under *his* answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers However, if you read my comment exchange with Flater, you will see my further thought. If it is a present tense irrealis (very unlikely) then it would seem to me correctly worded. What we are discussing is the difference between a present frustration and a past unfulfilled wish. If I am in a library and see a book I want to read I might say "I would have liked to borrow that, but I can't because my membership has expired". But explaining it to a friend later I would need to say "I would have liked to have borrowed it but..."

Comment: Hmm. Surely in your library scenario, when you're actually *there*, it should be Present Tense *I would **like** to borrow it, but I can't..,* Talking about it later, *I would **have liked** to borrow it, but I **couldn't...*** But I agree with your most recent "Going back to the question" comment under Colin's answer - there's a potential very fine distinction between "to take it home" / "to have taken it home" in terms of Past / Present irrealis, even though few of us would particularly notice "inappropriate" phrasing. *(And* it's starting to give me a headache thinking about it! :)

Comment: Actually no. You can say *I would have liked...* when you're actually there, since you're referring to an "unreal" situation (***if*** the "but..." clause hadn't been the case).

Comment: So if I had said "I would have liked to do sth" in the past, wouldn't I have referred to the "past before past" tense?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes - I agree with your last comment. Standing there in front of the bookshelf one could and probably would say "I would have liked to borrow this - if only my membership hadn't lapsed". But later me to you "I would have liked to have borrowed it if only my membership hadn't have lapsed". But I also agree that it is headache inducing...

Comment: @FumbleFingers This would have been better discussed on ELU. I do incidentally still believe I'm right - but the reason people haven't voted for it is that ELL is by definition comprised of learners. And it is too complex for people to bother getting their minds around. It cannot possibly be right, **when reporting a past event** to say "He would have loved to take it home". It has to be "He would have loved to have taken it home". And we are doing a disservice to learners if we do not make that clear.

Comment: @WS2: Oh, go on then! I think it's *your* turn to raise one of these "knotty" ELL issues on ELU (I think I may have done it last time a similar situation arose). But if you do, I shall definitely restrict myself to only engaging with the post for a limited number of minutes at a time (otherwise "brain ache" might turn into "brain **rot**" !!! :)

Comment: I found a very interesting article https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3941 which thoroughly explains similar sentences. For example, "I would have liked to have known Marilyn" would be interpreted as "Speaking at t2 I would have liked at t1 to have known Marilyn at some earlier point t0", but it contradicts many opinions written in this topic and seems to do the same with the chapter from the book (there are no t0 point there)

Comment: @Denis I don't quite see where t0 comes into it. "I would have liked (t2) to have known Marilyn(t2 or t1)" is my interpretation. But "know" seems a little different to "take" - perhaps because it is a stative verb.

Comment: As a non-native speaker I will abide by FumbleFinger's, Lambie's and Colin Fines's oppinions simultaneously. For me the situation is as follows: "He would have loved to take it home" means unequivocally that there was "still a possibility" at the author's present (which is past for the reader)="Obviously, he wanted to take it home". At the same time, "in fact he didn't take it home. The rest of the idea is implied".  The situation where that possibility was not realized would be "He would have loved to have taken it home"- I agree.

Comment: And, of course, there was no regret that Jack hadn't taken the book before. In the library scenario, as FumbleFingers noted, "when you're actually there, it should be Present Tense I would like to borrow it, but I can't.., Talking about it later, I would have liked to borrow it, but I couldn't..." - that's exactly how I will take it in. Why should it be "...to have borrowed" here?

Comment: There are a pair of inferences (by Flater and WS2) that have totally knocked me out. "I would have loved to take you out to dinner [but I won't because I know you're married to Bob]" is stating A PRESENT TENSE IRREALIS. How can "would+perfect" express the present irrealis? And the second one: "...if only my membership hadn't have lapsed" What is it - HADN'T HAVE LAPSED? Is this a valid construction? If so, could anyone spare me a link to any grammaar where it can be found?

Comment: @FumbleFingers In WS2's "...if only my membership hadn't have lapsed", is HADN'T HAVE LAPSED a valid construction? If so, could you spare me a link to any grammaar where it can be found?

Comment: @Eugene: According to pedants and "strict" grammar, that use of ***hadn't have*** is syntactically invalid. But ***I*** certainly use it, and so does WS2. See ["If I would have lost you" vs "If I had lost you"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/if-i-would-have-lost-you-vs-if-i-had-lost-you) as asked on ELU over 10 years ago.

Comment: @Eugene I have never said "I would have loved to have..." (i.e. would have + perfect) expresses a present irrealis. My third comment to Fumble Fingers on this thread makes it clear.

Comment: @WS2 Sorry for having misunderstood you. This is what the whole point is. Such costructions as "would+perfect infinitive" is referred to in all Grammars (at least intended for non-native learners) as one that attributes irrealis to actions/states in the past, as it is. Notwithstanding its taking place in the author's past. Here is what I allude to: "The police would have brought him in yesterday" (i.e. I may suppose the police did it yesterday or in the past irrealis: they would have done that if they had had the information about his location).

Comment: Or in narration: "Jack was strutting along the road musing about his future. The police would have brought him in some days ago if they had had the information about his location". The same is for the author's present which is past for the moment of reading: "Jack was skulking in his den. If he hadn' t been doing that the police would have brought him in at any moment". It's a pity but Grammars do not provide us with
other forms of expressing irrealis to us (such as "would+perf.inf + to + perf.inf.). And I don' t know why.

Comment: As to the OP's examples, I may be in the know of only two variants of bringing up the idea of Jack's regret that he hadn't taken the book earlier: He would he had taken it before or He would love/like to have taken it before. Is it possible to use "He would have been to have done that" instead of "He was to have done that"? If it is, what tinge of meaning will it accrue then?

Comment: @Eugene I'm sorry but I don't understand your last comment. Could you give me a simple example of the quotation you might wish to use, and the time at which the person is saying it.

Comment: @WS2 It is just a reflection of "I would have liked to have done that". Instead of "would like to..." I picked out "to be to...". "Jack needed to read this. He'd have been to have taken it home during his previous visit to pore over".

Comment: @Eugene "I would have liked to have done that" indicates that the opportunity occurred at a prior time and is now passed. If the opportunity were still there, but barred by "irrealis", then it would be "I would have liked to do that...". E.g. "I would have liked to interview the Chinese representative, but I can't because she doesn't speak English and I don't speak Chinese".

Comment: @WS2 I thought that "I would have liked to have done that" indicates that the opportunity occurred at a time prior to the author's present (which is past for the reader). I.e. "Jack needed to read this. He'd have loved to take it home..." - the author's present (for the reader it is past already). And "Jack needed to read this. He'd have loved to have taken it home a week before..." - the author's past.

Comment: @WS2 I've written a comment to the Colin Fine's answer with "He'd have agreed to have taken it home during his previous invasion a week before..." What would you think about it?

Comment: @Eugene I really feel I have said all that is necessary here. You need to go back and re-read some of the threads.